# Smb Outbound channel not transfering files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a service that takes a file and sends it to a SMB Messaging Gateway using Spring Integration. I created a directoryResolverService to handle determine remotedirectory path based on file sent. But it seems that i cannot connect to the remote directory.

```
fun saveFile(fileDto: FileDto) {
  try {
    val decodedFileContent = Base64.getDecoder().decode(fileDto.content)
    val file = FileUtil.constructFile(fileDto.filename)
    FileUtil.writeBytes(file,decodedFileContent);
    appLogger.info("writing local file to ${FileUtil.absolutePath(file)}")
    appLogger.info("Sending file to smb messaging gateway")
    smbMessagingGateway.toFileChannel(file)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      appLogger.error("Failed to store files to filechannel with message: ${e.cause}")
    }
}
```

```
@MessagingGateway
interface SmbMessagingGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "fileChannel")
    fun fileChannel(file: File?);
}
```

```
@Service
class DirectoryResolverService {
    fun resolveRemoteDirectory(file : File): String {
        return file.absolutePath
    }
}
```

```
@EnableIntegration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "file-server")
@Configuration

class SmbMessagingGatewayConfiguration {
    lateinit var host: String
    lateinit var username: String
    lateinit var password: String
    lateinit var remoteBaseDir: String

@Autowired
    lateinit var directoryResolverService: DirectoryResolverService

@Bean
 fun smbSessionFactory(): SessionFactory<SmbFile> {
   val smbSession = SmbSessionFactory()
    smbSession.host = host
    smbSession.username = username
    smbSession.password = password
    smbSession.port = 445
    smbSession.shareAndDir = remoteBaseDir
    smbSession.smbMinVersion = DialectVersion.SMB210
    smbSession.smbMaxVersion = DialectVersion.SMB311

     return smbSession
}

@Bean
    fun smbOutboundFlow(): IntegrationFlow? {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("fileChannel")
            .handle { file: File, _ ->
                val remoteDirectory = directoryResolverService.resolveRemoteDirectory(file)
                Smb.outboundAdapter(smbSessionFactory(), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                    .remoteDirectory(remoteDirectory)
            }
            .get()
    }

}
```

```
@Bean
fun smbOutboundFlow(): IntegrationFlow? {
 return IntegrationFlow.from(fileChannel)
  .handle(
   Smb.outboundAdapter(smbSessionFactory(), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
   .useTemporaryFileName(false)
   .autoCreateDirectory(true)
   .remoteDirectory(static)
    ).get()
}
```

Using this code i am able to send file but i have to declare the directory in the class. But i want to have a dynamic directory path based on file. Anyone experienced with this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your first example just creates a new adapter for each file; nothing will actually be sent to those adapters.

Assuming your resolver service is defined as a bean, instead of `.remoteDirectory(static)` use

```java
.remoteDirectoryExpression(@directoryResolverService.resolveRemoteDirectory(payload))
```

Comment: I don't think the `file.absolutePath` is a correct remote directory...